# How do I query by role using the easy_roles gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using easy_roles with Rails 4, but when I try to select all users with some role, I have below error: "undefined method `with_role'".

Gemfile:

```
gem "easy_roles"
```

app/models/user.rb:

```
easy_roles :roles
```

migration:

```
add_column :users, :roles, :string, :default => "--- [customer]"
```

controllers/users_controller:

```
@users = User.with_role("employee")
```

Comment: Why do you have your `user.rb` file in `modules` directory?

Comment: you have run `bundle` to install the gem after adding it to your gemfile right?

Comment: Did you restart your development server after running `bundle` and migrations?

Comment: Yes, I restarted development server

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `easy_roles :roles` line to your `User` model which *should* be located in `app/models/user.rb`.

Right now it seems you have added it in the wrong place (`modules/user.rb`).

Also after doing all the [steps described](https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles#basic-setup) in the README (Basic Setup section) you have to also run:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

even though the README forgot to state that.

Comment: Sorry, I have it already in app/models/user.rb. But still I have the same error.

Comment: Have you run `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Yes. And also I restarted my server.

Answer (score 0):

While this code is [in the easy_role codebase and appears well tested](https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles/blob/master/lib/methods/serialize.rb#L69), I've also never had it work out of the box for me.

Just place this in your class with the roles and you should be set:

```
scope :with_role, proc { |r|
  query = "#{self.table_name}.roles LIKE " + ['\'%',r,'%\''].join
  where(query)
}
```